# Php/Javascript Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, php, css, html, bootstrap-4

I have checked my code several times and it just seems to not work as when the PHP runs it just shows the following error in the browser console:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier.

I am not sure if this is just a simple problem or there is more to it.

```
    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"><h4 id="Txt"> Now In Development</h4></div>
    <form method="POST" action="#goHere">
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email For Updates">
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
     $email = htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['email']));

     $logname = 'list/email.txt';
     $logcontents = file_get_contents($logname);
     $searchfor = $email;

     // the following line prevents the browser from parsing this as HTML.
     //header('Content-Type: text/plain');

     // get the file contents, assuming the file to be readable (and exist)
     $contents = file_get_contents($logname);
     // escape special characters in the query
     $pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');
     // finalise the regular expression, matching the whole line
     $pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";
     // search, and store all matching occurences in $matches
     $filecontents = $email."\r\n";
     $fileopen = fopen($logname,'a+');
     $filewrite = fwrite($fileopen,$filecontents);
     $fileclose = fclose($fileopen);
     if($email == NULL) {
       echo '<Script> document.getElementById("Txt").innerHTML = "<div      class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">"You entered Nothing</div>"; </script>';
     } elseif(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
       echo '<Script> document.getElementById("Txt").innerHTML = "<div      class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Email was already added</div>"; </script>';
} else {
    if(!$fileopen or !$filewrite or !$fileclose) {
      echo '<Script> document.getElementById("Txt").innerHTML = "Thankyou"; </script>';
    } else {
        echo '<Script> document.getElementById("Txt").innerHTML = "<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Email Succefully Added"; </script>';
    }
  }   
}
```

Comment: you need to wrap php code using `<?php`

Comment: no <?php ?> wrappers i think....

Comment: php wrapper is there i just took this out of a project i am working on php works fine and executes.

Comment: could you quote the error so we can have a better detail of error..

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
i click on the error and it doesn't like the lines php is trying to execute
<Script> document.getElementById("Txt").innerHTML = "<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">You entered Nothing</div>"; </script>

Comment: Start <?php just before your `if` statement and put php end tag at last `?>`

Comment: There is Php tags before my if statement the php is working fine that is just a small part of my php code, that is just what the php executes to the DOM

Comment: @kylemccarthy please add the full error in question....or submit a screenshot in question... not in comment :) add an update ^_^

Comment: Escape quotation marks `"` inside `"<div class=\"alert alert-success\" role=\"alert\">Email Succefully Added"` and add closing `</div>`

Answer (score 0):

#### The problem

The problem is with the script tag strings.

If you inspect the outputted `<script>` tag, you might see something like this:

```
<script> document.getElementById("Txt").innerHTML = "<div      class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Email was already added</div>"; </script>
```

Note that the double quotes are not escaped within the HTML.

#### Possible Solutions

One way to resolve this is to escape the double-quotes inside the HTML:

```
echo '<Script> document.getElementById("Txt").innerHTML = "<div      class=\"alert alert-success\" role=\"alert\">Email was already added</div>"; </script>';
```

Or delimit the HTML using escaped single-quotes:

```
echo '<Script> document.getElementById("Txt").innerHTML = \'<div      class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Email was already added</div>\'; </script>';
```

Other options include [heredoc](http://php.net/heredoc) or possible [nowdoc](http://php.net/nowdoc) formatting, or a template engine.

See a demonstration of the escaped single-quote delimiter approach in [this phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/w1c2-pk3k).